# Local Pubsub Emulator won't work with Dataflow

Tags: java, eclipse, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-pubsub

I am developing Dataflow in Java, the input comes from a Pubsub. Later, I saw a guide [here](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/emulator) on how to use local Pubsub emulator so I would not need to deploy to GCP in order to test.

Here is my simple code:

```
private interface Options extends PipelineOptions, PubsubOptions, StreamingOptions {

    @Description("Pub/Sub topic to read messages from")
    String getTopic();
    void setTopic(String topic);

    @Description("Pub/Sub subscription to read messages from")
    String getSubscription();
    void setSubscription(String subscription);

    @Description("Local file output")
    String getOutput();
    void setOutput(String output);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Options options = PipelineOptionsFactory
            .fromArgs(args)
            .withValidation()
            .as(Options.class);
    options.setStreaming(true);
    options.setPubsubRootUrl("localhost:8085");

    Pipeline pipeline = Pipeline.create(options);
    pipeline
        .apply("IngestFromPubsub", PubsubIO.readStrings().fromTopic(options.getTopic()))
        // other .apply's

    pipeline.run();

}
```

I was able to follow the guide, including the part where I need to use the example Python code to create topic, subscription, publisher and even publish messages. When I use the Python code to interact with the Pubsub emulator, I notice the message `Detected HTTP/2 connection` in the command-line where I run the emulator:

```
Executing: cmd /c C:\...\google-cloud-sdk\platform\pubsub-emulator\bin\cloud-pubsub-emulator.bat --host=localhost --port=8085
[pubsub] This is the Google Pub/Sub fake.
[pubsub] Implementation may be incomplete or differ from the real system.
[pubsub] Apr 10, 2020 3:33:26 PM com.google.cloud.pubsub.testing.v1.Main main
[pubsub] INFO: IAM integration is disabled. IAM policy methods and ACL checks are not supported
[pubsub] Apr 10, 2020 3:33:26 PM io.gapi.emulators.netty.NettyUtil applyJava7LongHostnameWorkaround
[pubsub] INFO: Unable to apply Java 7 long hostname workaround.
[pubsub] Apr 10, 2020 3:33:27 PM com.google.cloud.pubsub.testing.v1.Main main
[pubsub] INFO: Server started, listening on 8085
[pubsub] Apr 10, 2020 3:34:38 PM io.gapi.emulators.grpc.GrpcServer$3 operationComplete
[pubsub] INFO: Adding handler(s) to newly registered Channel.
[pubsub] Apr 10, 2020 3:34:38 PM io.gapi.emulators.netty.HttpVersionRoutingHandler channelRead
[pubsub] INFO: Detected HTTP/2 connection.
[pubsub] Apr 10, 2020 3:34:52 PM io.gapi.emulators.grpc.GrpcServer$3 operationComplete
[pubsub] INFO: Adding handler(s) to newly registered Channel.
[pubsub] Apr 10, 2020 3:34:52 PM io.gapi.emulators.netty.HttpVersionRoutingHandler channelRead
[pubsub] INFO: Detected HTTP/2 connection.
```

I compiled/run the code in Eclipse using Dataflow Pipeline Run Configuration, but I get a problem.

[image]
[image]
[image]

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline$PipelineExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to create subscription: 
...
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to create subscription: 
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.pubsub.PubsubUnboundedSource.createRandomSubscription(PubsubUnboundedSource.java:1427)
...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: localhost
...
Caused by: java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: localhost
```

When I try to add `http` in the line `options.setPubsubRootUrl("localhost:8085")`, I get an infinitely repeated exception:

```
com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest execute
WARNING: exception thrown while executing request
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
```

It seems to reach the Pubsub emulator but can't connect as the command-line where I run the emulator generates this infinitely also:

```
[pubsub] Apr 10, 2020 3:49:30 PM io.gapi.emulators.grpc.GrpcServer$3 operationComplete
[pubsub] INFO: Adding handler(s) to newly registered Channel.
[pubsub] Apr 10, 2020 3:49:30 PM io.gapi.emulators.netty.HttpVersionRoutingHandler channelRead
[pubsub] INFO: Detected non-HTTP/2 connection.
```

How can I make my Dataflow work with Pubsub emulator?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are attempting to connect to the Pubsub emulator from the Beam Direct Runner, using the Dataflow fork of the Beam 2.5 SDK. The Dataflow 2.5 SDK and Eclipse plugin were deprecated as of June 6, 2019. However this should work.

You need to prefix your PubsubRootUrl with 'http://' in Beam, as you've discovered. The second problem you are seeing indicates that nothing is listening on `localhost:8085`. This is likely because there are actually 2 localhosts: IPv4 and IPv6. The Pubsub Emulator only listens on IPv4 and Windows tries IPv6 first. Try replacing `localhost` with `127.0.0.1` to force IPv4. You should end up with this:

```
options.setPubsubRootUrl("http://127.0.0.1:8085")
```

Comment: I'm having this same problem (though I am on OSX) and have tried your solution @andrew-pilloud, but things are no different.... any other ideas?

Comment: @user2738206 Wondering if you got this working. I have tried setting the root url to the format mentioned in the answer but still receives connection refused. Your help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Besides setting the root URL, you also need to provide a credential factory. When working with the emulator, you don't need any credentials. You can do it either using the code (by setting the option manually) or just pass command line. The latter keeps your code clean.

Code:

```
options.setPubsubRootUrl("http://127.0.0.1:8085");
options.setCredentialFactoryClass(NoCredentialsFactory.class);
```

Command line options:

```
--pubsubRootUrl=http://127.0.0.1:8085
--credentialFactoryClass=ca.dataedu.dataflow.otlpdemo.NoCredentialsFactory
```

The `NoCredentialsFactory` code is something like:

```
import com.google.auth.Credentials;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.gcp.auth.CredentialFactory;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.options.PipelineOptions;
import org.checkerframework.checker.nullness.qual.Nullable;

public class NoCredentialsFactory implements CredentialFactory{

    private static final NoCredentialsFactory INSTANCE = new NoCredentialsFactory();

    public static NoCredentialsFactory fromOptions(PipelineOptions options) {
        return INSTANCE;
    }

    @Override
    public @Nullable Credentials getCredential() {
        return null;
    }
}
```